# Projection text on video in android

Tags: android

I want project a text like bubble on video when I capturing video. I mean in live capturing video in android grammatically.

I think that is like augmented reality but very new in this field.

For more please check following image. It can help you to understand my opinion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode: In **Activity** you will have a **VideoView**. In front of your **VideoView** (over), you can place a **SurfaceView**, and you can programmatically show your bubble at the that precise time and position, when you want it.

You can get inspired from [here](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) or [here](https://github.com/JDaren/subtitleConverter).